# Get data from mongodb built using mongoose models and node by python using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I have a database built using node and mongodb(using mongoose) that is used to support a website. Basically this uses Schemas. Now, I need to query this database in python using flask and I am using Pymongo for this. This database has only one collection.

```html
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = databaseName
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = databaseURL

mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = mongo.db
collection = db[collectionName]
collection_list = collection.find({'model':'familySchema'})

#There is only one entry related to 'familySchema' model. 

for document in collection_list:
    print(document)

# This is what gets printed
# {'_id': ObjectId('5a8d144970512751d3d9e0d9'), 'model': 'familySchema', 'field': '_id', 'count': 95, '__v': 0}
```

So, when I query the database, I get the result as shown above. The `count` key showing `95` is correct as there are 95 entries related to the model(I added them in the website). But I am unable to access them. All I get is the model name and the number of entries in it. I want to access all the entries using that model. I am a beginner in using mongo and need some help in this. Any suggestions on how to do this?

In node, it is done like this.

```html
autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var UnknownSchema = new Schema({
    pictureType: {type: String},
    location: {type: String},
    leafname: {type: String},
    createduser: {type: String},
    lastedituser: {type: String},
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
UnknownSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin,'UnknownSchema');

var addUnknown=mongoose.model('addUnknown', UnknownSchema);


//It is fetched like this
var getUnknown=function(req,res){
    addUnknown.find({},function (err,data) {
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: You appear to be looking at the `identitycounters'` collection, instead of the `'familyschemas'` or whatever the actual collection name for the data is. At any rate that collection is used by `mongoose-autoincrement` to persist the "counter" information for incrementing updates. It's not where the actual data is.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also turns out I am accessing the wrong database. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have been thinking for the past few days that I am accessing database in wrong way.